# PHP script redirecting to install.php

Tags: php, mysql, hosting

**DESCRIPTION:** I have a normal HTML website (say, https://example.com) and it has been hosted on Hostinger. Last week, I purchased a PHP script from CodeCanyon. I had put this application on this URL https://example.com/VideoDownloader. The website is running perfectly, but, I'm facing problem with this PHP script.

For the first time, if you visit this URL, it'll redirect you to install.php page. Once you install the script (which takes less than 2 mins), you can immediately start using the application by visiting the same URL. Now, it'll not redirect you to install.php.

**PROBLEM:** The script works perfectly for 1-2 days. The problem is after 2 days, the application breaks and it starts redirecting you to install.php page again. And, again you have to install it to make it work. This cycle keeps on repeating.

There is nothing wrong with the code and it is running perfectly in my localhost. The version of PHP in localhost is the same as that on my Hostinger server.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED:** I tested the script in my localhost and it is running perfectly without breaking. Searching on the internet was not much helpful. However, I got the hint that the issue may be related to the MySQL database to upper/lower case characters.

Please, guide me on this.

Website file structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without errors or other information do not think many will / can help you. I suggest checking your error / access logs first.